# How do I prevent widgets from moving around on the dashboard?

Tags: macos, dashboard

Is there a way to disable moving widgets around in the dashboard? I have a neat layout all set up, and would like to prevent accidental widget movements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Finder, press <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>G</kbd> and type `~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.dashboard.plist` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>. Press <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>I</kbd> to bring up the file information pane. Click the **Locked** checkbox.

This will not prevent you from moving widgets around,opening new widgets, etc., but will preserve the arranged state of widgets at the time of locking such that any future time you launch Dashboard (rebooting, logging in, restarting Dock, etc), they will be preserved in their state at the time you locked the Dashboard.

Comment: Nice tip. Coupled with a restart dock extension for Alfred, I can restore my layout if I mess it up. But I would infinitely prefer not being able to move widgets at all...

Comment: Working on it. But I thought this was a helpful start.

Answer (score 0):

I am using Doc Unlocker 2 for this

http://www.apple.com/downloads/dashboard/networking_security/dockunlocker2.html

Comment: This locks the position of items in the Dock, not the position of items in the Dashboard.